# magento add many additional price to cart, and user can choose one

Tags: cart

Assumption : A customer added a mobile phone worth ₹2000 to cart Situation : Our client wants the customer to select one recharge amount for eg. ₹100(from many available recharge amount eg. ₹50, ₹100, ₹150, ₹200, ₹250) in cart, these amount can be added from admin backend. And the final price of product is ₹2100. (for each product customers have to select the recharge amount seperately) Modifying the price would reflect in many areas like invoice, email exchange, checkout total.

In which module the price calculations are there? and whats the better way to achieve this?

Any steps to do this or a sample piece of code would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking here. Is it so that if customer buys this particular item for ₹2000 he must also buy one of recharge amounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try making custom options for products as recharge amount.
 
Reference Link : http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/difference-between-custom-variants-options-and-configurable-product-type

Comment: im creating simple product with custom options (radio box with many price), thanks this works fine for me...

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using a [bundled product](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product) where product A is the phone and product B is a choice between any number of recharging amounts.

The bundled product also allows you to give a certain reduction on buying this combination as a user.

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable to use configurable product which includes product variants where a person can choose mobile phone and variations would be Rs.50, Rs.100, Rs.200 and so on....

Please view this link for details : 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_product/producttype#configurable

Comment: This would require you to make several simple products of the same phone just with a different recharge amount. The recharge amount would not be a product in itself and would not be reusable for other phone bundles. This way you would end up with a lot of products, much more than should be required

Comment: Can you give an example of how you exactly want things to appear on your magento store?